# why do I get a capability error saying that I need to add a capability in my python code?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots

Please check the error at this link. I am getting this error. Since I am new here, I can't add images. I get this error when I run the code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XFH3.png

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def account_info():
    with open('account_info.txt','r') as f:
        info = f.read().split()
        email = info[0]
        password = info[1]
    return email, password

email, password = account_info()

tweet = 'Hello world, this is Jarvis'

option = Options()
option.add_argument('start-maximised')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options)

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question with the error. Do not post images as code

Comment: sorry for my mistake @MendelG  I am new here so I didn't know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a slight error. You are passing in the `Options` object to the `options` parameter of the webdriver. Instead, pass in the instance of `Options` you just made.

```py
# code continues above

tweet = 'Hello world, this is Jarvis'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximised')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
```